# didUpdateToLocation is not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I want to receive location updates.
I have added a location delegate to the header:

`@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

and the following functions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //initialize location manager
    CLLocationManager* locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    // [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController"     bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //Some problem
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    //Some action
}
```

But neither `didUpdateToLocation` nor `didFailWithError` are called (same problem on the simulator and on the device). What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

Luda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are location services for your application enabled?

P.S: it would help to make your location manager an instance variable so it will be retained by ARC after the method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is completed.

Comment: this is the likely case when ARC is releasing ur variable in the middle of process and hence none of the delegates are being called.

Comment: I think that's what I meant with my P.S. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a necro, but I searched high and low for an answer on this and couldn't find a solution for my similar situation, this seems like the best spot for it.

I made a Delegate object with a custom initializer that sets some flags then runs [self->locationManager startUpdatingLocation], and invoke it as such in a viewDidLoad:

```
myLocationGetter* __unused getter = [[myLocationGetter alloc]initAndUpdateOnce;
```

Neither didUpdateToLocation nor didFailWithError was getting called. Seems like ARC was forgetting about my getter object before the callbacks came through. Solved the problem by declaring getter as an instance var in the view controller and initializing it in viewDidLoad.